# Rspec 2: How to render_views by default for all controller specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rspec2

I'm always writing `render_views` in all my controller specs:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe AwesomeController do
  render_views
end
```

Is there any way to always render views on all controller specs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [documented](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-5/docs/controller-specs/render-views#render-views-globally) way to do so, as of today is the following

> spec/support/render_views.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.render_views
end
```

Comment: I just keep it in my `spec_helper.rb`, but it's the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Add this to `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
config.include(Module.new {
  def self.included(base)
    base.render_views
  end
}, :type => :controller)
```

It creates an anonymous module, that runs `render_views` on the class it is included in, and it is included on any describe-block that describes a controller.

Comment: I also much prefer this over `config.render_views`.  This comes in super-handy when testing controllers that use jbuilder

Answer (score 2):

### Add It To Your `spec_helper.rb` Config.

You can add `render_views` to your rspec config, like so:

**In Your `spec_helper.rb`**:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  # Renders views in controllers.
  config.render_views

  # Other config setup.

end
```

### Turning Off `render_views`.

You can turn off view rendering on a per describe/context basis with `render_views false`, like so:

```
context "without view rendering even with global render_views on" do
  render_views false

  # specs without view rendering.
end
```